# Не работают самые простые функции PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

Стоит задача вывести всех пользователей и их данные в виде отчета(excel файл).
На сервере установлена старая версия php и нет возможности её поменять, поэтому использую старую библиотеку PHPExcel.

Везде встречаю вот такую документацию. Самые простые операции

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';
$xls = new PHPExcel();
$xls->getProperties()->setTitle("Название");
$xls->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$sheet = $xls->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setTitle('Название листа');
$sheet->setCellValue("A1", "Значение");
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.xls");
```

Но файл получается без всех этих настроек и значений. Ячейки все пустые или же выводят содержимое php-страницы. 
Решение пока такое. На сервере формирую $html = таблица данных

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';
$xls = new PHPExcel();
$xls_data = ob_get_clean();
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.xls");
echo $xls_data;
echo $users; //тут вывод таблицы с данным
```

В итоге, я получаю файл с нужными данными, но естественно без каких-либо стилей и самое главное я не могу понять почему не работают простые операции с документации

Comment: Но в примере же еще как минимум есть `$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');`.

Comment: Код на рабочем компьютере, а он без доступа в интернет, поэтому код перепечатывал)
В самом коде есть и эти строчки, но все также.